# Error in with the search function

Tags: php

I've added a search function in my site and It's working fine. But I've encountered a problem that the uppercase and lowercase letters are valued differently. Both the words "the" and "THE" shows different results. How can I resolve this ?

I'm trying this:

```php
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entries
    WHERE (`id` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`date` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`title` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`contents` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: mysql is not case-sensitive by default.
please describe it in detail

Comment: @DivyaKumari : As I told you mysql is not case-sensitive  so try to debug query by printing it and run into phpmyadmin

Comment: `mysql` _can be case-insensitive_ when comparing strings and text. ;-/ Example for the `LIKE` comparison: `col_name LIKE 'a%' COLLATE latin1_bin`. Details:  [B.5.5.1 Case Sensitivity in String Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html). And: [MySQL collation charts](http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mysql is not case-sensitive](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html). So case-sensitivity is not the issue here. But I can see that you are using the same variable for different columns. So columns datatype may affect adversely here. So you can try with all lowercase like this:

```
$query = strtolower($query);

$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE (LOWER(id) LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (LOWER(date) LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (LOWER(title) LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (LOWER(contents) LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

I've no idea about your id and date field datatype.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, it worked !! 
I'm making a blog where those datatypes are required..